# using string parser and passing input file to arraylist

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

Hi there i'm trying to read a file and store it on array list but i'm stuck here. I need to also use String.split() which I do not know where to put in. is there anything that I have missed out?

My code is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee
{
    private ArrayList<Employee> employees;
    private String name;
    public Employee()
    {
        employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        name = "";
    }

    public void readFile()
    {
        String filename = ("employees.txt");

        try
        {   FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);

            try
            {
                while (parser.NextLine())
                {
                    Scanner parser = new Scanner(inputFile);
                    String employeeType = parser.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(employeeType);
                    String employeeNumber = parser.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(employeeNumber);
                    String employeeName = parser.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(employeeName);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                System.out.println("Closing file");
                inputFile.close();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
        {
            System.out.println(filename + "not found");
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Unexpected I/O error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding few lines from `employees.txt` file to illustrate the format in which you are keeping the `Employee` data might help. Also, please note, that it looks like you have there data like `employeeType` and `employeeNumber` and you don't have such fields in your `Employee` class, therefore you won't have where to store this data inside your class.

Comment: Where do I initiate the fields for the type then because when it complies, it shows "no files found"

Comment: The problem that you are describing is most probably because the program cannot find the file, and is a different problem from the one with the fields. You'll need to solve them one by one. In order for the file to be accessible to your application, you need to add it to the classpath. Maybe add description of your file structure to your question description so someone here can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have and input file as follows:

> jinny programmer 50000
>   john manager 75000

You've set up a few things correctly, but what you have to consider is how you instantiate Employee (which appears to only have a no argument constructor). Let's say `Employee` has a name, a title, and a salary. These are the attributes of your `Employee`. As you read in your file, you want to set these attributes of a single `Employee` type as you read each line, whose attributes are split by a whitespace character in the sample file.

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private Integer salary;

    //constructor + getters + setters
}
```

Additionally, for each employee encountered you will want to build a collection, outside of employee that contains your employee information.

Consider the following example of what may exist outside of the `Employee` class. This would be how you collect your employees from your data file, and populate the attributes of the employee.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Employees> employees = readFile();

    //continue work on employees here
}

public static List<Employee> readFile()
{
    String filename = ("employees.txt");

    try
    {   FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

        try
        {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                Employee e = new Employee();

                String line = scanner.nextLine();

                String [] lineSplit = line.split(" ");

                //populate employees here OR use a constructor on employee that accepts all 3 parameters
            }
        }

     //continue implementation here
```